# Why Django "migrate" reports OK for apps that have been skipped from migration?

Tags: django, migration

I created custom database Router and properly configured it (and the database aliases) in settings.py. The router defines allow_migrate() method - which explicitly skips (returns False) undesired apps. Basically, there are two key requirements:

1. Allow migrations ONLY for a given set of "desired" apps
2. For those "desired" apps - allow migration only in a certain database

I have very detailed unit test script that validates ALL possible test cases and proves everything is "routed" the way it should. I included debug print statements that print message when migration is allowed (returns True), and when I apply migrations (run "migrate") that includes both "desired" and "undesired" apps - it produces stdout (saying that migration for such-and-such app is allowed) ONLY for the right migrations.

But... the output also includes "Applying ... OK" for all the rest apps (for which allow_migrate() returned False) as well. In the database, I see migrations applied ONLY to desired apps - but "migrations" table lists all of the migrations (both applied and the ones that are not applied).

WHY "migrations" table gets records for migrations that have not truly been applied (and stdout shows OK)?

*What am I missing - how can I avoid migrations to be considered as applied if allow_migrate() returns False?*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the migrations system was designed this way, but I agree with you that this behavior is undesirable.

This is an [accepted issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23273) (see my comment [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23273#comment:13) in particular) but unfortunately there's no resolution on the horizon, and I don't know of a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is functioning exactly in a manner that it is described.

> makemigrations always creates migrations for model changes, but if
> allow_migrate() returns False, **any migration operations for the
> model_name will be silently skipped** when running migrate on the db.

Unfortunately implementation of the allow_migrate is not really considering a lot of use cases in my opinion, as it does not stop migration from being run which fills the migration history

---

allow_migrate check is inside of each migration operation  and it is not meant to disallow full migration ( probably because of migration dependency history or something else)

for example postgres database_forwards method of  Operation class looks [like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5e07601b233a50e6bcca438f65fd7028277f78b/django/contrib/postgres/operations.py#L18)

```
def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
    if (
        schema_editor.connection.vendor != 'postgresql' or
        not router.allow_migrate(schema_editor.connection.alias, app_label)
    ):
        return
```

For your own use case you would need to write your own solution and have allow_migrate checks prior to this ( look into [migrate](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5e07601b233a50e6bcca438f65fd7028277f78b/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py) management command and start from there )